# CSS - image in display:table-cell expands beyond parent

Tags: css

I'm trying to size an image in a table-cell to be no larger than the height/width of the table-cell, but it's not working.

[image]

```
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  z-index: 8;
}
.container {
  position: fixed;
  left: 5%;
  top: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;

  }
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  background: #eee;
  }
.table .cell {
  display: table-cell;
  }
.table .cell.left {
  width: 240px;
  background: #fff;
  }
.table .cell img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  }
```

As you can see on the screen shot, I have two cells, one on the left which is white and one on the right which contains the image. The table is in the background in #eee, and is the proper height/width (it fits to .container), but the cells overflow the table height when the image is larger than its parent cell, and setting max-height and max-width for the image has no effect - it just sizes to its original size.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="cell left">
        //white
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <img src="" /.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle.net?

Comment: ... or can you post some HTML?

Comment: I made this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wf_4/ZVh4g/ but I cant reproduce your problem. What browser are you using?

Comment: That JS fiddle DOES reproduce the problem. You'll notice the fake image goes off the bottom of the screen and there's no 5% margin, but since the div is fixed there's no overflow/scroll bar.

Answer (score 1):

you can't set height as a %, any rules set like this will be ignored and the pictures original height will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Those are just two guesses:

Try to add rows with "display: table-row"? You can then apply row height and max-height either by em/px or % each row.

Also try using "overflow: hidden;" or "overflow: none" at your rows and cells.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best I can do for now is change it to a background image and use background-size: contain;, which is an imperfect solution but more simplistic than using javascript. I can't find another work-around.